# How to search for an element by custom HTML attribute using Coded UI Tests

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, coded-ui-tests

I have a bunch of `input[type=submit]` buttons inside a GridView. The `id`s and `name`s of these buttons, while predictable because they use an index number, are not well suited to automation using SpecFlow and Coded UI Tests. I'm finding it difficult to search for those button elements.

A snippet of the HTML delivered to the browser:

```
<input type="submit" id="abc_xyz_0" data-task-id="123" value="Apply">
<input type="submit" id="qrs_tuv_0" data-task-id="345" value="Renew">
```

The button text is generic in each row ("Apply" and "Renew"), but the `data-task-id` attribute is unique. I would like to use this attribute and value to identify a button to click on. I'm trying to use the `SearchProperties` and `FilterProperties` but I keep getting exceptions:

> System.NotSupportedException: The property DataTaskId is not supported for this control.

How I'm attempting to find the control:

```
HtmlInputButton button = new HtmlInputButton(document);

button.SearchProperties["data-task-id"] = "123";
// or button.SearchProperties["DataTaskId"] = "123";
```

Some additional details:

- Windows 7
- Internet Explorer 11
- Web site delivered from `localhost` and is marked "trusted" in the Internet Options Security Settings

---

Update: Thanks to both marcel de vries and AfroMogli for their answers. Marcel's uses JavaScript to find the element, and AfroMogli's uses pure C# and the CodedUI API. Both answers worked equally well, and I didn't notice a performance difference between either one. Two equally good solutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can accomplish this by searching with the ControlDefinition as propertyname. The following line of code did the trick for me:

```
HtmlInputButton button = new HtmlInputButton(document);
button.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition, "data-task-id=\"123\"", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));
```

Example method allowing you to pass in any attribute name and value:

```
public HtmlInputButton InputButton(string attributeName, string attributeValue, UITestControl container = null)
{
    string controlDefinition = string.Format("{0}=\"{1}\"", attributeName, attributeValue);
    HtmlInputButton button = new HtmlInputButton(container ?? document);
    button.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition, controlDefinition, PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));

    return button;
}
```

**EDIT**:

Or if the attribute name doesn't change, do the following?

```
public PropertyExpression GetByTaskId(string value) 
{
  return new PropertyExpression(
    HtmlControl.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition, 
    $"data-task-id=\"{value}\"", 
    PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains
  );
}

HtmlInputButton button = new HtmlInputButton(document);
button.SearchProperties.Add(GetByTaskId("123"));
```

Comment: I'll have to try this out. Ideally I'd like a solution that doesn't involve running JavaScript against the browser.

Comment: Great, please get back to us about how it went :)

Comment: This worked great! I also like how its a pure Coded UI Test solution. I'm torn. I wish I could mark yours and marcel de vries' answers as the solution.

Comment: Great! Yeah, you don't want to execute JS code when there is a pure Coded UI test solution as alternative. But the JS solution worked aswell so I understand that you're torn :)

Comment: Just be aware that with this solution you can't run it against chrome and Firefox since the cross browser plugin does not support the use of ControlDefinition. this is something I asked the team multiple times to fix, but has not changed yet. I would like this solution also better, but preferred the javascrip one so I can run it cross browser.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way of doing this is by using a simple javascript execute to get the control based on any attribute name and value you provide. something like this:

```
const string javascript = "return document.querySelector('{0}');";
var bw = BrowserWindow.Launch("your page");
string selector = "[data-task-id]='123']";
var control = bw.ExecuteScript(string.Format(javascript,selector));`
```

The variable control now contains the control you are looking for and is of the correct type. So if it is e.g. and HtmlHyperLink you can use it as such right a way.

I have a longer story about how to use this in Angular sites here: http://fluentbytes.com/testing-angular-sites-with-codedui/ since angular uses even custom attributes like ng-*

Comment: The `ExecuteScript` method is always returning `null` for me. I read the blog post, and using the `ControlDefinition` as a filter doesn't find the element either. Need to do more digging

Comment: I'm pausing the debugger and using `window.ExecuteScript("document.querySelector('body');")` and even this is returning `null` (the "window" field is a BrowserWindow object).

Comment: I tried `window.ExecuteScript("alert('foo');")` and it shows the browser alert just fine. JavaScript is executing, it's just not capturing the return value of the script.

Comment: I figured it out. For whatever goofy reason I had to `return document.querySelector(...)` in the eval'd JavaScript. I've edited your answer to reflect that (if that's OK). +1 and marked as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Well the goofy reason is because you are returning an object to the CodedUI engine. that is exactly why I provided the JavaScript code that contains the return statement. It was something I forgot the first time as well. CodedUI will pick up the object you return and then create an instance of the correct HtmlControl type for you to interact with right away.

Comment: Since AfroMogli's answer is in pure C#, I switched the solution to his answer, although yours works perfectly fine too. The only problem I've come across is I've had some situations where I didn't have access to the `BrowserWindow` object in order to execute JavaScript.

Comment: I understand, but be aware that this has a significant downside. You can not run the solution provided by AfroMogli's cross browser. So when you run this against chrome or Firefox the test will fail, since control definitions are still not supported for cross browser playback

Comment: That's interesting to know. This isn't a bad tidbit of information to add to your answer, actually.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote these utility methods to test both the JavaScript and direct solutions explained in other answers here.

I found that although the `ControlDefinition` property did not initially work cross-browser (with Chrome) using the out-of-the-box [Selenium Cross-Browser Components](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AtinBansal.SeleniumcomponentsforCodedUICrossBrowserTesting) available on the Visual Studio Marketplace (v1.7), everything started working as expected after [upgrading](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) the `chromedriver.exe` (to v2.41).

Be aware the upgraded `chromedriver.exe` must be 'unblocked' before it will work. I used PowerShell's `Unblock-File` command to do this, **note** this must be started using `Run as Administrator` to succeed.

**Utility methods:**

```
public PropertyExpression GetByCustomAttribute(string attributeName, string value)
{
    return new PropertyExpression(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition,
                                  $"{attributeName}=\"{value}\"",
                                  PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);
}

public static T GetControlByCustomAttribute<T>(this BrowserWindow browserWindow,
                                               string attributeName,
                                               string value,
                                               HtmlControl context = null)
     where T : HtmlControl
{
    string queryContext = (context != null ? "arguments[0]" : "document");
    string script = $"return {queryContext}.querySelector(\"[{attributeName}=\'{value}\']\");";
    return browserWindow.ExecuteScript(script, context) as T;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "chrome";
var browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("index.html"));

// first find parent of item with custom data attribute
var div = new HtmlControl(browser);
div.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id, "myDiv");

// Either using ControlDefinition solution:
HtmlEdit edit1 = new HtmlEdit(div);
edit1.SearchProperties.Add(GetByItemId("4711"));

// Or using JavaScript solution:
HtmlEdit edit2 = browser.GetControlByItemId<HtmlEdit>("4711", div);

// use control...
edit1.Text = "text";
edit2.Text = "text";
```